# How to deal with slighltly broken JSON in JavaScript Node?

Tags: javascript, json

I am making a request to an API and most of the time the response that I receive is valid JSON, however, occasionally the JSON is a little broken and JavaScript can not deal with it.

Consider this request as an example: https://www.nike.com.br/ProductLookup/555088-041

When you paste the JSON into this website: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ the JSON formatter on the website realises that the JSON is broken, but manages to repair it just fine.

Is there a way I repair do this within JavaScript?

Here is a snippet of my code where it breaks:

```
async function scraper(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.waitFor(2000)
    await page.goto(url);
    const content = await page.content();

    if (initialFlag) {
        innerText = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let wholeJson = JSON.parse(document.querySelector("body").innerText);
            let status = wholeJson[0].status;
            if (status === "REMOVED") {
                return {status: status}
            }
```

It breaks on the line `innerText = await page.evaluate(() => {`.

The full error message is:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 1831
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:34
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\Users\user\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:217:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\Users\user\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:106:16)
    at async scraper (C:\Users\user\Documents\Node Projects\bergi.js:23:21)
    at async main (C:\Users\user\Documents\Node Projects\bergi.js:77:27)
```